# proof that if $e^{z+\lambda}=e^z$ then $\lambda=2k \pi i$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$, i want to prove that $e^{z+\lambda}=e^z$ then $\lambda=2k \pi i$, I should take $z=x+iy$ s.t.

If $e^{z+\lambda}=e^z$, $e^{x+iy+\lambda}=e^z$  then $e^{x}e^{iy} e^{\lambda}=e^xe^{iy}$, and I can take $e^{\lambda}=1$ , but note that:

$$e^{i2k\pi} e^{ix}=e^{i2k\pi +ix}=e^{i(2k\pi +x)}= \cos(x+2k\pi)+i\sin(x+2k\pi)= \cos(x)+i\sin(x)=e^{ix}.$$

This means $e^{i2k\pi}=1$, thus $2k\pi i=\lambda$. This can work?, i'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Equivalently, as you have noted down: $e^z$ satisfies the property that $e^z e^w = e^{z+w}$ for any two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ and that $e^w =1$ if and only if for some integer $k$, $w=2\pi ki$.

Comment: $e^{z}=e^{z+\lambda}=e^{z}e^{\lambda}$ and you can cancel $e^{z}$ because it is not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is fine: you show that $e^{z+\lambda} = e^z \implies e^\lambda = 1$. I probably wouldn't split $z$ into its real and imaginary components. Instead, I would say,
$$e^{z+\lambda} = e^z \implies e^{-z} e^{z + \lambda} = e^{-z}e^z \implies e^{-z + z + \lambda} = e^0 \implies e^\lambda = 1.$$
This works just as well in complex numbers as it does in real numbers.

The next step is somewhat garbled. First, and most importantly, you simply show that $e^{i2\pi k} = 1$, or in particular, $\lambda = i2\pi k \implies e^\lambda = 1$. This is not what you are being asked to show! You need to show $e^\lambda = 1 \implies \lambda = i2\pi k$ for some integer $k$, i.e. the converse. Just because you found a class of complex numbers that produce $1$ when raised as a power of $e$, does not mean that you've found them all!

Also, as a side note, reintroducing $x$ seems unnecessary. You could have just written instead

> $$e^{i2k\pi} = e^{i2k\pi}= \cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)= \cos(0)+i\sin(0)=1.$$

Instead, I would now express $\lambda$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts, say $\lambda = \alpha + i \beta$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{R}$. Then, by the definition of complex exponential,
$$1 + 0i = e^\lambda = e^{\alpha + i\beta} = e^\alpha(\cos(\beta) + i \sin(\beta)),$$
or equating the real and imaginary parts,
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
1 &= e^\alpha\cos(\beta) \\
0 &= e^\alpha\sin(\beta)
\end{aligned}\right.$$
This is now a system of two equations purely in $\Bbb{R}$. Can you solve it from here?

Comment: It seems that from the last system of equalities it follows that the only values of $\beta$ and $\alpha$ would be $\alpha=0$, $\beta=(2 \pi k)$, or not?

Comment: @Wrloord Indeed! Though you may need to write down some extra steps to conclude this.

Comment: Thank you for your great help